# Running individual apps in HiDPI mode

Tags: macos, mac

Is there a way to lunch individual apps in HiDPI mode? I would like to set my MacBook Pro Retina to full 1:1 pixel resolution with SwitchResX/SetResX, and then on a case-by-case basis either use the larger button & font settings or launch the app in HiDPI mode to allow me to allocate the pixels where they're most useful

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<string>True</string>
```

to the `Contents/Info.plist` file.

Original article: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j52Ac.jpg (not affiliated)

Note: this technique does not work on Photoshop CS6